# Why does the last phase of Irving's Stable Roommates Matching work

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Pertaining to the [Stable Roommates Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem) and the algorithm developed by Robert W. Irving.

There are two (sometimes broken into three) phases in which we may come to a stable pairing of everyone in a set and their stated preferences. The first, and sometimes recognized second, simple rejection phase(s) are pretty self explanatory as to how and why they work. But the final *rotation/cyclic* phase has been hard to grasp. The goal is to find rotations and eliminate/reject pairs found in the rotations until stable matching is found/not found. This phase is pretty hard to explain in words so I'll try my best and hope someone already knows this problem.

My wording:

We will start with any person's remaining preference list and select the second remaining preference `person1[2]`. Use `person1[2]`'s own list and select their last remaining preference `person2[L]`. We use these as our starting pair `(person1[2],person2[L])`. With `person2[L]` we will repeat the above process (by selecting `person2[L]`'s second preference, and that persons last preference) and continue until we have once again rotated around back to our original pair of `(person1[2],person2[L])`. At that point we will reject all diagonal pairs `(personI[2],previous personJ[L])`. The rotation/reject-diagonal-pairs repeats until everyone has a single match or until it is declared that not everyone can be matched.

Algorithm's pseudocode:

```
FOR all rotations in (p1...pn) and (q1...qn)
such that qi is second preference of pi and pi+1 is last preference of qi 
DO:
    FOR i = 1...n -1 DO:
    reject(qi,pi+1)
    END
END
```

The code seems fine to implement, but is pretty hard to grasp as to why it works. I have yet to find a good video or article explaining this phase.